# how to get hashmap object value

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

i have a code which put object as hashmap value. I want to read lat and lng from the hashmap using iterator class. But i dont know how to do this.here is my code.

```
Location locobj = new Location();
HashMap loc = new HashMap();

while(rs.next()){
      locobj.setLat(lat);
      locobj.setLng(lon);
      loc.put(location, locobj);

}

      Set set = loc.entrySet();
      Iterator i = set.iterator();
      while(i.hasNext()) {
      Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
      System.out.println(me.getKey()+"value>>"+me.getValue()); 
      }
```

class location is like this

```
public class Location {

    private String lat;
    private String lng;
    private String name;

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }
    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }
    public String getLng() {
        return lng;
    }
    public void setLng(String lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

how do i read locobj lat and lng value from getValue() method.please help

Comment: what is the problem exactly?

Comment: System.out.println(me.getKey()+"value>>"+me.getValue()); here iwant to the lat and lng value by calling getLat() and getLng() method. how do i do that using me.getValue()...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just cast the value?

```
Location locobj = (Location)me.getValue();
locobj.getLat();
locobj.getLng();
```

Answer (score 5):

You should make use of generics here.
Declare Map as

```
Map<String, Location> locationMap = new HashMap<>() // assuming your key is of string type
```

That way, you can avoid typecasting (RTTI should be avoided - one of the design principles)

```
Location locobj = me.getValue()
locobj.getLat() // will give you latitude
locobj.getLng() // will give you longitude
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to use Generics.

Instead of

```
Location locobj = new Location();
Map<Location> loc = new HashMap<Location>(); // code to interfaces, and use Generics
```

do

```
Location locobj = new Location();
HashMap<String,Location> loc = new HashMap<String,Location>();
```

and your entry as

```
Map.Entry<String,Location> me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
```

Then you won't have to cast anything

Answer (score 0):

[getValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29) returns you reference to Object, but in fact object is Location. So you need to perform casting, see answer from @DataNucleus, but you can do even like this:

```
System.out.println(me.getKey()+"value>>"+((Location)me.getValue()).getLng());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving an Object with getKey() or getValue(). You need to now call the getter methods to print the appropriate values.

Answer (score 0):

The following can be used:

```
for (Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object values = (Object) entry.getValue();
    System.out.println("Key = " + key);
    System.out.println("Values = " + values + "n");
}
```